# Selecting items in a dataframe until a certain date (python, datetime)

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe DF having a column 'myDate' such that:

```
>>> type(DF['myDate'][0])
3: <type 'datetime.date'>
>>> print(DF['myDate'][0])
2013-06-15
```

So, the column is of type "datetime.date".
In order to select only the items belonging to the year 2014 I tried:

```
DF[[DF['myDate'] < datetime.date(year = 2015, month = 1, day = 1)]]
```

It gives me back an error:

> ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 2041412.

Which is the correct way?

Comment: It would be simpler to have the `dtype` as a `datetime` then you can just do `df[df['myDate'].dt.year == 2015]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an excessive pair of `[]`:

`DF[[DF['myDate'] < datetime.date(year = 2015, month = 1, day = 1)]]`

should be

`DF[DF['myDate'] < datetime.date(year = 2015, month = 1, day = 1)]`